# dot in number being converted to comma in varchar with insert into select statement

Tags: java, oracle, select, jdbc, insert

I am writing a JDBC code to insert data to a table by selecting few records from a source table.

A column is marked as number [6,2] in source table Oracle. But the same is marked as varchar in the destination table.

That is a simple query using insert into ... select..

I am not converting the number to char in the query.

This works fine with few Windows machine. If the source table is having the data as 0.98, the destination table is also having the value as 0.98

But in few Windows machine, If the source is having the value 0.98, the destination is having the value as 0,98.  < dot is replaced with comma>

OJDBC14 & JDK 1.7 is being used in both machines.

Is there any idea on who is changing the dot to comma.

Please help.

Comment: I would guess that it has to do with the REGION and Language settings in the PC. Many countries use `,` as a decimal separator and `.` as thousands separator.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. let me check the region settings in both machines

Answer (score 1):

Direction provided by Icarus is more accurate to fix the issue at source.

Below snippet will help to resolve, override the regional settings in JAVA:

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
Locale newLocale = new Locale("en", "US");
locale.setDefault(newLocale);
```

Thanks,
Vasanth.

Answer (score 0):

On a number whether a comma (,) or dot (.) will be used as a decimals separator depending of the database environment NLS setup.

In any case when selecting from a table a column number you can use the below example.

```
select to_char(n,'000.000') from t;
```